# Linux + how to verify the CPU performance

Tags: linux, cpu, top

I have few servers that I manage in my origination ( red-hat 5 )
my users complain about the bad CPU performance

```
 grep processor /proc/cpuinfo
   processor       : 0
   processor       : 1
```

can I get advice what is the best command/tool/sanity that point on bad CPU performance

from TOP command

```
Cpu(s):  0.3%us,  0.5%sy,  0.0%ni, 98.2%id,  0.7%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.3%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   8043444k total,  7832040k used,   211404k free,   236004k buffers
Swap:  2097144k total,   555464k used,  1541680k free,  6184604k cache
```

Second question - If I add another two CPU's on this VM machine, can this action will help to the performance issue?

Comment: How your users known that the CPU is in cause? Could describe their problems?

Comment: they run the top , and 98.2%id display from the top ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `98.2%id` means that most of the time, CPU does nothing (The CPU is in idle state).

To determine how is used the CPU over time, you can use `uptime` command that will gives you the [load average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_(computing)).

Answer (score 1):

`i7z` is a tool that reports Intel Core i7, i5 and i3 CPU information about Turbo Boost, per core CPU frequencies, multipliers, temperature as well as times spent in the C0/C1/C3/C6/C7 states, all in real time.

To install type the following command:

```
yum install i7z
```

Or, to install the i7z Qt GUI, use:

```
yum install i7z-gui
```

Comment: With a redhat 5, `yum install` will work better...

Answer (score 0):

You can use sar([sysstat](https://github.com/sysstat/sysstat)) to monitor your system and check load over time. The sar logs generates a file which can be opened with kSar command. Also, from kSar you can run sar commands through ssh and generate logs on the fly.

Do you have something specific running on the server? Like a JVM or some other application? For example for JVM you can use jconsole to check if garbage collection is affecting performance on the server.

In case there is a JVM running on the server:

For jconsole I recommend not running it on the server since it can be pretty hard at times on the system. Run it on a remote system and configure jmxremote on the server to connect.

Also, what kind of issues are the users facing?

Made this into an answer since I can't post a comment yet.